# Metric space separable implies its cardinality $\leq \mathfrak{c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, metric-spaces, cardinals

Let a metric space $(X,d)$ be separable. Then $|X|\le \mathfrak{c}$.

The way I'm thinking of proving this is as follows:

(1) Since $(X,d)$ is separable, there is a dense subspace $Y\subset X$ such that $\overline{Y}=X$, with $Y$ being countable.

(2) Then there exists an injection $f:Y\to \mathbb{N}$.

(3) But $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Q}|=\aleph_0$. Thus there exists a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$.

(4) Then $g\circ f:Y\to \mathbb{Q}$ is an injection.

(5) But $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed in the following way:

$$\mathbb{R}=\{(q_n)_{n=1}^\infty : \forall 0<\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}, \exists n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}\mbox{ such that } m,n\ge n_\varepsilon \implies |q_m-q_n|<\varepsilon \}$$

(6) So there is an injection $h: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$.

(7) Thus $h\circ g\circ f: Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is an injection.

(8) Hence, $|X|\le \mathfrak{c}$.

Please let me know whether or not you find this proof outline to be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, all you show is that there is an injection from a countable set into the real numbers. And well... isn't that obvious since $\Bbb{N\subseteq R}$?

Here is a key step in the proof: In a metric space, sequences determine the topology. Specifically, every point in the metric space is the limit of a sequence from $Y$, your countable dense subset.

How many sequences are there?

(For bonus points, show that we can actually find a canonical sequence converging to each point, after fixing an enumeration of $Y$.)

Comment: It appears that what needs to be proved is that $|X|\not > \mathfrak{c}$. I'm not sure how we can deduce this from the fact that there are at least as many unique convergent sequences in $Y$ as there are points in $X$.

Comment: No, that's not "at least". That's "at most" points in $X$ as convergent sequences from $Y$. How many sequences does $Y$ have, convergent or otherwise?

Comment: What I meant by "at least" was that there can be more than one sequence converging to the same point in $X$. $Y$ has $\aleph_0$ many sequences converging to points in $Y$, if I'm correct, plus the limit points $\not\in Y$ of those sequences. But how do we know how many sequences converging to points not in $Y$ there are?

Comment: Do you mean there are $|\mathcal{P}(Y)|\le 2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$ sequences there? If $Y$ is infinite (but since it's dense in $X$, it should be infinite), then, I think, it should be $|\mathcal{P}(Y)|=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$.